# Swift playground - How to convert a string with comma to a string with decimal

Tags: swift, string, number-formatting, swift-playground

I'm new in the Swift world.

How can I converting a String with a comma to a String with a decimal?

The code work's fine with a dot (.)

The problem is when I'm using a comma (,) ... with: **var price**

The origin of the problem is the Decimal french keyboard use a comma (,) instead of a dot (.)

Don't know exactly how to use **NSNumberFormatter** or **generatesDecimalNumbers** if it's the key. There's probebly more than one options.

```
//The answer change if "2,25" or "2.25" is used.

var price      : String = "2,25"
var priceFloat = (price as NSString).floatValue

//I need to have 2.25 as answer.

var costString = String(format:"%.2f", priceFloat)
```

Thank's for your time and your help!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

update: **Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2**
You can use NumberFormatter() to convert your string to number. You just need to specify the decimalSeparator as follow:

```
extension String {
    static let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    var doubleValue: Double {
        String.numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."
        if let result =  String.numberFormatter.number(from: self) {
            return result.doubleValue
        } else {
            String.numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ","
            if let result = String.numberFormatter.number(from: self) {
                return result.doubleValue
            }
        }
        return 0
    }
}


"2.25".doubleValue // 2.25
"2,25".doubleValue // 2.25

let price = "2,25"
let costString = String(format:"%.2f", price.doubleValue)   // "2.25"
```

You should do the currency formatting also with NumberFormat, so create a read-only computed property currency extending FloatingPoint protocol to return a formatted string from the String doubleValue property.

```
extension NumberFormatter {
    convenience init(style: Style) {
        self.init()
        self.numberStyle = style
    }
}
extension Formatter {
    static let currency = NumberFormatter(style: .currency)
}
extension FloatingPoint {
    var currency: String {
        return Formatter.currency.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}
```

---

```
let costString = "2,25".doubleValue.currency   // "$2.25"
```

---

```
Formatter.currency.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
"2222.25".doubleValue.currency    // "$2,222.25"
"2222,25".doubleValue.currency    // "$2,222.25"

Formatter.currency.locale = Locale(identifier: "pt_BR")
"2222.25".doubleValue.currency    // "R$2.222,25"
"2222,25".doubleValue.currency    // "R$2.222,25"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use for this **Swift 3**:

```
let currentAmount = "2,50"

currentAmount = currentAmount.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")

print(currentAmount) // "2.50\n"
```

Comment: Still valid in Swift 4.2

Comment: saved me in Swift 5

Comment: Don't use it as doesn't work for locales which use a comma for grouping and periods for decimals, i.e. 18,154.00.

Answer (score 5):

```
var price = "2,25"
price = price.replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: ".")
var priceFloat = (price as NSString).floatValue
```

Comment: Surely you have the "." and "," the wrong way around here?

Answer (score 1):

Nullable extension version:

```
extension String 
{
    static let customNumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    var doubleValue: Double? {
        String.customNumberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."
        if let result =  String.customNumberFormatter.number(from: self) {
            return result.doubleValue
        } else {
            String.customNumberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ","
            if let result = String.customNumberFormatter.number(from: self) {
                return result.doubleValue
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of accepted answer, I've also made numberFormatter private for safety reasons.

```
extension String {
    private static let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

    var doubleValue: Double {
        String.numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."
    
        if let result = String.numberFormatter.number(from: self) {
            return result.doubleValue
        }
        String.numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ","
        return String.numberFormatter.number(from: self)?.doubleValue ?? 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I liked this simple approach

```
extension Double {
        func removeZerosFromEnd() -> String {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            let number = NSNumber(value: self)
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 1
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 16
            formatter.decimalSeparator = "."
            return String(formatter.string(from: number) ?? "")
        }
    }
```

Removes zeros from end and uses dot as a separator instead of comma

Answer (score -2):

EDIT: Updated to work with the current version of Swift:

```
let amount = "8,35"

var counter: Int = 0
var noCommaNumber: String!
for var carattere in (amount) {
    if carattere == "," { carattere = "." }
    if counter != 0 { noCommaNumber = "\(noCommaNumber ?? "\(carattere)")" + "\(carattere)" } else { noCommaNumber = "\(carattere)" } // otherwise first record will always be nil
    counter += 1
}

let importo = Float(noCommaNumber)
```