# Swift - Add dot in Number Pad Keyboard

Tags: swift, keyboard, numpad

How to add dot in Number Pad Keyboard?
I want when I use notification UIKeyboardDidShowNotification a UIButton to appear over down left side of the Number Pad keyboard.

This will be the frame of the button:
`let dotButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 162, view.frame.width/3, 54))` ,
but it has to be added as subview of the number pad keyboard to prevent hiding from it, how will be done ?

Edit:
I made it to appear like this

```
    dotButton.addTarget(self, action: "addDot:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    dotButton.setTitle(".", forState: .Normal)
    dotButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 25)
    dotButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        let keyboardView:UIView = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows.last?.subviews.first as! UIView
        self.dotButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, keyboardView.frame.size.height-54, self.view.frame.width/3, 54)
        keyboardView.addSubview(self.dotButton)
        keyboardView.bringSubviewToFront(self.dotButton)
    })
```

but now I don't know how when I click to the button to add . in the textField with method addDot I don't know how to tell to the textField to add a . need help again...

Edit2:
I made a class variable which is `textFieldInEdit:UITextField!`
and in `func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool`
I do this `textFieldInEdit = textField` and now my function `addDot` is:

`textFieldWhichEdit.text = "\(textFieldWhichEdit.text)."` ,

but I've got another problem now.. I have fields with different keyboard types how to detect which keyboard appears and show the dot on the Number Pad only ?

Edit3:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if(textField.keyboardType.rawValue==4){
        textFieldWhichEdit = textField
        dotButton.hidden = false
    }else{
        dotButton.hidden = true
    }
}
```

Done I've made a dot button on Number Pad keyboard :)
If someone know better method can write it and I will accept the answer :)

Comment: You can make your text field accept comma for decimal fractions input

Comment: I want . for making Doubles :)

Comment: I know I have already answered this question let me find the answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28314223/2303865

Comment: Thanks a lot I will use it for security later, but I still want . to be shown on Number Pad Keyboard.

Comment: You should find the solution in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192303/how-to-add-a-done-button-to-numpad-keyboard-in-ios7

Comment: Did you try DecimalPad as keyboard type?

Comment: @HoaParis I copy the code that you gave me and I have another problem now check the question again I wrote an update

Comment: I added an answer with another solution. The solution the link that I send to you add the button in the toolbar instead of the keyboard layout.

Comment: I made a second update

Comment: Try the solution that I've posted, using shouldChangeCharactersInRange. Beware that the decimal point could be . or ,

Comment: Check this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359365/2599596

Answer (score 38):

yourTextField.keyboardType = .decimalPad

Comment: Decimal pad has "," not "."

Comment: @SavasAdar yours has a comma because of your localization.

Comment: I want my TF to consider the decimal as a first character if the decimal is pressed. I will write the logic to append '0' at first pos if someone directly enters '.'

Comment: This is not working on iOS 13. No pontuction button appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Add UITextfieldDelegate to your controller, then link you text field again an IBOulet (tfTest for example), then implement the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` call-back like this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var tfTest: UITextField!

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    var newText: NSString = textField.text as NSString
    newText = newText.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)

    var isEmptyNew = (newText as String).rangeOfString(".", options: NSStringCompareOptions.allZeros, range: nil, locale: nil)?.isEmpty ?? true

    if isEmptyNew {
        //change to decimal pad as we allow to add decimal point now
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad

        //refresh responder to change keyboard layout
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }

    var isEmptyOld = textField.text.rangeOfString(".", options: NSStringCompareOptions.allZeros, range: nil, locale: nil)?.isEmpty ?? true

    //if pressed button is the dot and your text field has already a dot, do not allow this. Normally, this case does not happen cause your keyboard type was changed to number pad before
    if string == "." && !isEmptyOld {
        return false
    } else {
        //show just numbers
        textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
        //refresh responder to change keyboard layout
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        textField.becomeFirstResponder()

        return true
    }
}
```

To avoid problem with the decimal separator (. or ,), use this code to retrieve the decimal separator and use it instead of hard code value

```
let df  = NSNumberFormatter()
df.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()

let decimalPoint = df.decimalSeparator ?? "."
```

Comment: No, before couple of months, I done it but I delete the code and now I don't remember how to do it...