# Numeric keyboard with decimal

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I´m building an app with equations and I have used a numeric keyboard but I want to have a decimal slot on it. The default is only numbers. How do you add a decimal input on that keyboard?

This is the code I use to get the numeric keyboard

```
.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
```

Comment: textfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation;

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Simply change the keyboard type:

```
self.someTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIKeyboardType) for all the keyboard types.

Answer (score 16):

Select *Decimal Pad* in Keyboard Type for Text Field in Attribute Inspector.

Refer the image below for more detail

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In storyboard go to Attribute Inspector. There you can change keyboard type.[You can check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShTYo.png)

Answer (score 4):

set keyboard type to textField in swift 3

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtNumber: UITextField!  

override func viewDidLoad(){

    self.txtNumber.keyboardType = .decimalPad
}
```

Comment: For iPad you need restrict user to decimal only. Number pad is not available on iPad. In shouldChangeCharactersIn delegate method add following code

    let numCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789")
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return numCharacterSet.isSuperset(of: characterSet)